# Trigger file download on a page with content

Tags: php, html, download

I have seen many websites triggering a file save-as dialog on a page with existing HTML content. How do they do this?

I know about setting the right headers such as Content-disposition etc. but when I do that, the content of the page does not load, and immediately the file download is triggered...

Comment: The question is interesting, but if you're interested, you can find it out for yourself with a combination of the browser's "view source" feature and Fiddler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a regular HTML page, then add a META refresh that redirects to a PHP script that sends the file with a `Content-Disposition` header.

For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=download.php">
```

Comment: So, just to clarify, this would refresh the page and therefore download the file at download.php, but leave the page being viewed intact? If so, great answer!

Comment: The problem with this method (as opposed to using `iframe`s) is what happens when the script that should send the file from the server encounters errors. If it sends the errors they would override the currently open page, where as when requested from an `iframe` the error messages will appear in that `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

I know a lot of them use a hidden iframe, the page that the iframe points towards is actually a file download.

Although there are better ways to do this, I'm sure.

Comment: Yeah iframe is one method I seemed to find... But it's not that widely supported, like in Opera... I was wondering if there are any other techniques.

Comment: Slaks answer would work, and is probably the best way to do it. :)