# Rails 3 file download wizard

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, download

I wrote an app that takes you through a 2 step wizard - one page collects information, the other is an agreement.  When you click Agree the page loads a "Downloading this file..." page, and then should start actually downloading the file, overall a pretty common task.  However, I'm struggling with a solution in Rails.  Ideally I would think to just render the "Downloading page..." and then make a call to send_file, but you can't do this as it results in a DoulbeRender error.

What is a good way to load a page and then subsequently initiate a file download in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to render the download page, and then send the user to a separate action which sends your file.  Generally this is accomplished with a meta tag, see [Trigger file download on a page with content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923262/trigger-file-download-on-a-page-with-content) for a PHP example.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.